# Nivo Slider in wordpress post not showing caption

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider

I have nivo slider in wordpress post but it is not showing caption. I tried using css then all the caption showed up. The code in which the slider is working on is

`

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-light">
      <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <?php
                    $args=array(
                            'post_type'=>'featuredevent',
                            'order'  => 'ASC');
                            $banner=new WP_Query($args);
                            while($banner->have_posts()):$banner->the_post();?>
        <div class="caption">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
          <?php the_title();?>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
      </div>
```

`